# Error in names(dat) when attempting bayesian model

Tags: r, brms

Getting an error that I can't figure out how to bypass.  I am using R version 4.3.1 and brms version 2.20.4.  I have also tried using brms::brm() syntax to no avail.

The error I am getting on the bay_mod line is

```
Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 'names' attribute [1] must be
 the same length as the vector [0].
```

I am setting up my R code as follows:

```
TS = ts(act_data$data, start = 2020, frequency = 12)
##fake time series data that mirrors the potential data can be generated 
##using the following, but should note that real data will have more patterning
## TS = ts(data = abs(rnorm(43)), start = 2020, frequency = 12)
length(TS)
#length of data is 43
x = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "1 month", length.out = 43)
df1 = data.frame(x=x, y=TS)
bay_mod = brm(formula = bf(y ~ ar() + s(x, bs = "cc")), data = df1, chains = 4, iter = 2000)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added comments to the code that represent how a fake dataset can be generated that is similar to what could be seen in the TS I am using.

Comment: I don't get the error when I run this without the smooth terms, `s()`. This suggests it's something in that component, and the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033437/error-in-gam-function-in-namesx-value-names-attribute-must-be-the-same-l suggests it might have to do with whether `x` is numeric or date.

Answer (score 0):

@gregor-fausto answered the question with:

I don't get the error when I run this without the smooth terms, s(). This suggests it's something in that component, and the related question [Error in gam function in names(x) <- value: 'names' attribute must be the same length as the vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033437/) suggests it might have to do with whether x is numeric or date.

Ultimately the error was due to me using Date in lieu of numeric values.